# Identify bush with white puff and 3 petal flowers, is it poisonous?

Tags: species-identification, flowers

Is this one of the poisonous bushes I should worry about? Tiny white puff of flowers along with 3 petal flower.   What is it?[image]

Answer (score 2):

You haven't told us where you live, but it must be somewhere in the Eastern USA, as your plant appears to be the native *Hydrangea arborescens*.  More info available [here](https://grownative.org/native_plants/wild-hydrangea/) and many other places on the internet.

Comment: That’s absolutely it!